# GitHub Pages Deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-pages

Whenever I try to deploy my react build to GitHub pages, it gives me a "The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files." (Screenshot attacked below)
[image]

https://github.com/Siarune/siarune.github.io

I can't find anything that would be wrong, but this is imported from a different project because I started using Next.js.

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start -p $PORT",
"predeploy": "yarn run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",  
"test": "next test",
"eject": "next eject",
"lint": "next lint"},
```

Comment: You probably already checked this, but does the `build` directory exist?

Comment: First, you cannot deploy such app to GitHub pages. Your app should be pure static, i.e. without any API or SSR/ISR. Second, Next.js doesn't generate a `build` directory. It generates a `.next` directory which GitHub pages don't understand. Third, there is nothing like `next eject`. Fourth, if you want you can generate statically exported HTML using `next build && next export`, it will generate an `out` directory. You can deploy it then to GitHub pages. You also need to create a `.nojekyll` file in `out` directory, that will prevent GitHub pages' Jekyll engine from blocking `_next` routes.

Answer (score 0):

It completely hosts' static site , you can use similar tools like vercel/heroku.
Further you may map the domain name too CNAME